# X-Frame-Options Header Not Set in Apache Tomcat 8.5.9

Tags: java, apache, security, tomcat, httpresponse

I am using Apache Tomcat 8.5.9 server for Java Web application with struts2, spring and spring-security. While doing security testing using "**Zap 2.7.0 security scanning Tool**" I got following errors in a scanning report of my web application.

1. X-Frame-Options Header Not Set
2. Web Browser XSS Protection Not Enabled
3. X-Content-Type-Options Header Missing

For this I used the following code in Apache Tomcat 8.5.9 server's **web.xml** file in conf folder.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported> 
    <init-param>
    <param-name>antiClickJackingEnabled</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>antiClickJackingOption</param-name>
    <param-value>SAMEORIGIN</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>xssProtectionEnabled</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>blockContentTypeSniffingEnabled</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>   
</filter>
<filter-mapping> 
<filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name> 
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>    
</filter-mapping>
```

Even after using the above code errors are not getting fixed. But it is working fine when I try to use above code in Apache Tomcat 7.0.5

Can anyone tell what am I missing in Apache Tomcat 8.5.9 server.

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem when i wanted show a pdf in a `<iframe></iframe>`. I did do this.

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/jspf/**").addResourceLocations("/jspf/");
//      registry.addResourceHandler("/Portafolios/**").addResourceLocations("/Portafolios/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/portafolio/**")
            .addResourceLocations("file:"+System.getProperty("user.home")+"/Documents/PPP/")
            .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(2, TimeUnit.HOURS).cachePublic());

        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
    }
```

I put my pdfs in portafolio directory. Also i modifed the web.xml of the Apache tomcat.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>antiClickJackingEnabled</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>antiClickJackingOption</param-name>
        <param-value>SAMEORIGIN</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

I modifed the configure() method of the SecurityConfig class.

```
@Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
            http
                .headers()
                .frameOptions()
                .sameOrigin()
                .contentSecurityPolicy("frame-ancestors 'self'").and()
            .and()
         .....
         other things
         .....
       }
```

You may have the web.xml but I think you are missing modify the configure() method. You could check the page of [spring](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/headers.html)